# Responsive height of website

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask how can I set responsive height of page, on bigger resultions like macbook etc... On these screens is my page vertically smaller than i need. I tried many things but nothing worked.

[On my pc it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdJGt.png)

[Bigger resultions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4c7b.png)

You can see that white space on bottom of the site on second img...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#top_bar {
 display:none;
}
.container {
 max-width: 964px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.bar {
 margin-top: 10px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.bar span {
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
 display:inline-block;
}
.bar ul {
 padding-left:0;
}
/*DROP DOWN*/
nav li{
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
nav {
  width: 600px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
nav a {
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
}
nav h3 {
  margin-left:38px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#3c3c50;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a#pull {
  display: none;
  text-indent: 30px;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 851px) {
  nav { 
    width:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    position: relative
  }
  nav li a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  nav a h3 {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  #last {
    margin-bottom:42px;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: url("img/nav-icon.png") no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:85px;
    top:11px;
  }
}
#top_bar ul a:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color:#3c3c50;
  border-bottom:1px #3995aa solid;
}
/**/
.header ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.header li {
 float:left;
}
.header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#3c3c50;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: "Open Sans";
 padding:20px 20px;
}
.header li a:hover {
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#3995aa;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #30869a;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color:#3995aa;
  color:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:75px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 172px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom:2px #e6e6e6 solid;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.header #top_bar a {
 padding: 20px 0px;
}

/*MAIN*/
/* GALERIA */
.photo {
 float:left;
 width:20%;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}
.photo img {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
.photo a {
 width:100%;
}
.gallery {
 width:100%;
}
.rollover {
 opacity: 1;
 -o-transition-duration: 1s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
 background:url(img/plus.png) bottom right no-repeat rgb(28,28,28);
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0;
}
.rollover:hover {
 opacity: .7;
 -o-transition-duration: 1s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
#roll-text,
#roll-date {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 max-width:250px;
 text-align:left;
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-family: "Open Sans";
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#roll-text {
 margin-top:20%;
}
#roll-date {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.main-content {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 color:#343340;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 25px;
}
.text {
 height:490px;
}
.main-content p {
 max-width:850px;
 font-family: "Open Sans";
}
#last{
 max-width:650px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.container .text  {
 max-width:850px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn {
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.btn a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #3995aa;
 padding: 15px 25px;
 font-family:"Open Sans";
}
.footer {
 height:200px;
 background-color: #363939;
}
.footer .container {
 height:179px;
}
.info  {
 float:left;
 display:block;
 color:#fff;
 max-width:348px;
 line-height: 18px;
}
.info h3 {
 font-family:"Open Sans";
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.info p {
 font-family:Arial;
 color:#fff;
 margin-top:15px; 
 font-size: 12px;
}
.info a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.contact {
 float:right;
 background-color: #3ba7bf;
 color:#fff;
 width:477px;
 height:199px;
}
.contact h3 {
 font-family:"Open Sans";
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin:10px 0 10px 50px;
}
.contact p {
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 width:40%;
 display:inline-block;
 line-height: 7px;
}
.copyright {
 color:#fff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color: #292b2b;
}
.copyright p {
 text-align: center;
 display:inline-block;
}
.wrap  {
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.right {
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 width:55%;
 margin-top: -122px;
 line-height: 7px;
}
.right p {
 width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 851px) {
 .header ul {
  display: none;
 }
 #top_bar {
  display:block;
 } 
 .text {
  padding:0 20px;
 }
  .info {
  float:none;
  text-align: center
 }
 .container .info  {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .contact,
 .copyright {
  float:none;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
 }
  .contact .container {
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
 .contact h3,
 .contact p {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px
 }
 .info h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
 }
 .contact {
  height:70px;
 }
 .copyright {
  height:30px;
 }
 .copyright p {
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
 }
 #last {
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
 }
 .rollover {
  display:none;
 }
 .photo {
  margin-bottom: 10px
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LegArt</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/n6vo44Re5QaWo8oCKShBs7/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">legart</a></li>
          <li><a href="">náš tím</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">právne služby<span>&#709;</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Partner</a>
                <a href="#">Kolegovia</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">právne služby<span>&#709;</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Právo duševného vlastníctva</a>
                <a href="#">Rodinné právo</a>
                  <a href="#">Konkurzné právo</a>
                  <a href="#">Správne právo</a>
                  <a href="#">Sporová a nesporová agenda</a>
                  <a href="#">Ochrana spotrebiteľa</a>
                  <a href="#">Pracovné právo</a>
                  <a href="#">Dopravné právo</a>
                  <a href="#">Nehnuteľnosti</a>
                  <a href="#">Obchodné právo a právo obch. spol.</a>
              </div>
            </li>

          <li><a href="">kontaktujte nás</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="top_bar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Leg Art</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Náš tím</a></li> 
                <li><h3>Právne služby <span> &#709;</span></h3></li>
                <li><a href="#">Právo duševného vlastníctva</a>
                 <li><a href="#">Rodinné právo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Konkurzné právo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Správne právo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sporová a nesporová agenda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ochrana spotrebiteľa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pracovné právo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dopravné právo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nehnuteľnosti</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Obchodné právo a právo obch. spol.</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontaktujte nás</a></li> 
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull"></a>
        </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="photo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/fourth-image.png">
          <div class="rollover" >
            <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
            <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="photo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/second-image.png">
          <div class="rollover" >
            <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
            <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="photo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/third-image.png">
          <div class="rollover" >
            <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
            <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="photo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/fourth-image.png">
          <div class="rollover" >
            <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
            <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="photo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/second-image.png">
          <div class="rollover" >
            <p id="roll-text">Odťahovanie vozidiel z verejných komunikácií súkromnou spoločnosťou</p>
            <p id="roll-date">24. November 2014</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text">
          <p>
            Advokátska kancelária LEGART s.r.o. je mladá, dynamicky sa rozvíjajúca advokátska kancelária, ktorá svojou činnosťou nadväzuje na činnosť zakladajúcej advokátky, JUDr. Zuzany Bukvišovej. Advokátska kancelária LEGART s.r.o. poskytuje komplexné právne služby v rôznych oblastiach slovenského práva tak v slovenskom ako aj v anglickom alebo nemeckom jazyku.
          </p>
          <p>
            Cieľom advokátskej kancelárie je spokojnosť klienta, ktorú naša advokátska kancelária dosahuje v dôsledku kladenia dôrazu na komunikáciu, promptnosť, profesionálny a vysoko odborný prístup k problémom a požiadavkám klienta.
          </p>
          <p id="last">
            Ak hľadáte spoľahlivého partnera na riešenie Vašich právnych problémov, neváhajte nás kontaktovať. 
            Radi Vás osobne presvedčíme o našich kvalitách.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="btn">
          <a href="#">kontaktujte nás</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="info">
          <h3>Najnovšie články</h3>
          <a href="#"><p>- Nariadenie technickej kontroly pravidelnej mimo   ustanovených lehôt 15. júna 2015</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>- Nový zákon o ochrane oznamovateľov 12. mája 2015</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>- Protikorupčný manuál 24. novembra 2014</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="contact-bar">
            <h3>Kontakt</h3>
            <p>LEGART s.r.o.</p>
            <p>Nitrianska 3, 821 08 Bratislava</p>
            <p>Tel. číslo: +421 2 4425 1232</p>
            <p>Email: bukvisova@legart.sk</p>
            <div class="right">
            <p>IČO: 47 252 332</p>
            <p>DIČ: 2024021637</p>
            <p>IČ DPH: SK2024021637</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
        <div class="wrap">
          <p>Legart Copyright © 2016.</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the meta tag viewport to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

Then set your html body to full viewport height (vh unit):

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: It´s same, nothing happened :/

Comment: I believe the OP's issue is that the footer does not stick to the bottom of the page when there's not enough content. If so, this answer does not address this.

Comment: @hungerstar, quite probably you are right, that's why I upvoted you. I just addressed the responsive height issue on different sources.

Comment: There is not any Command that center whole content vertically like margin: 0 auto works on width?  I have this problem mainly on sites which i need without scroll bar...

Comment: @JakubMiškovič if you use @hungerstar complete solution, with flexbox you can use `vertical-align: middle`, in the elements with `display: flex` set.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for a **Sticky Footer** solution.

Here is a basic demo using `flexbox` and a viewport unit `vh` to set the height.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: indianred;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}

footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Content
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

#### Support

- [Viewport Units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
- [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

If you need a little more support than viewport units provide you can swap out `height: 100vh` for:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```